# mysql import to varchar field contains something I don't see

Tags: php, mysql, load, varchar

I have been looking for this problem since a while so I guess I stuck. 
Case is: I'm importing a large csv file into mysql database with Bigdump (thanks to A. Ozerov), delimiter is |, all is fine, this works. 
In my last varchar field the values are usually: '', 'X', '1', '0'. Problem is if I do a select query to this field and look up values with '', I find none or one only. I checked a few lines one by one and found that the phpmyadmin shows a "textarea" instead of a textbox. I went and selected the field data and nothing was there (not even a carriage return). Still I could save the line and reopen it, when the textarea changed to textbox.
I wonder if anyone ever saw this error, and if there is a way to fix this database runtime from php (part of daily process), not line-by-line.

I even tried to copy paste both the csv and the database field to text editor to see if a char is there that I don't see.

The data I want to use is:
0 if the value is empty, 1 if the value is anything else. Currently I am not able to separate this two for the above reason.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check to see if its `NULL` by using `WHERE field IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for hexcidecimal values in the column by doing this:

```
SELECT HEX(columnname)
```

Then use REPLACE to change the Hex values to Null or ''

Comment: Yup, correct. Values are: 0A '',580A  'X', 310A '1', 58 'X'. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way or a setting in bigdump, where I can remove '0A' line breaks from the end of each read line?

Comment: I think a lot of these chars come from different languages, so you may want to try SHOW VARIABLES; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; to make sure that the database is UTF8.  Restoring to a UTF8 collated db might resolve the problem.